# Why does this method not properly sort the arrays for larger numbers?

Tags: java, sorting

I'm fairly new to Java, and I'm currently learning sorting algorithms. I was making my own merge sort algorithm, and I ran across a strange problem while doing so. I've added my code for my mergeArrays method (which is supposed to merge and sort two sorted arrays) below, and the problem is that it works for smaller numbers, e.g. {9, 13, 89, 199} and {1, 89, 127}, but it does not work for bigger ones, e.g. {9, 13, 89, 5000} and {1, 89, 5001}, as it ends up repeating the second largest number i.e. it outputs {1, 9, 13, 89, 5000, 5000} instead of {1, 9, 13, 89, 5000, 5001}. I just don't understand why this is the case, I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone can help!

Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

public class MergeSortExample
{
  public Integer[] mergeArrays (Integer[] nums1, Integer[] nums2)
  {
    Integer[] nums = new Integer[nums1.length + nums2.length];

    int nums1First = 0, nums2First = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
      nums[i] = Math.min (nums1[nums1First], nums2[nums2First]);
      if (nums[i] == nums1[nums1First])
      {
        if (nums1First == nums1.length - 1)
        {
          nums1[nums1First] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        else
        {
          nums1First++;
        }
      }
      else if (nums[i] == nums2[nums2First])
      {
        if (nums2First == nums2.length - 1)
        {
          nums2[nums2First] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        else
        {
          nums2First++;
        }
      }
    }
    return nums;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    /*Integer[] num1 = {9, 13, 89, 5000};
      Integer[] num2 = {1, 89, 5001}; does not work*/

    Integer[] num1 = {9, 13, 89, 199}; //works
    Integer[] num2 = {1, 89, 127}; //works

    MergeSortExample m = new MergeSortExample ();
    Integer[] testMerge = m.mergeArrays (num1, num2);

    for (int i = 0; i < testMerge.length - 1; i++)
    {
      System.out.print (testMerge[i] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println (testMerge[testMerge.length - 1]);   
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  Please [edit] your question to indicate what you are expecting, why you are expecting it, what you are observing, and why it is wrong.

Comment: @Joe C Sorry for that, edited just now!

Comment: change every `Integer` to `int` (except `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) and it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer` means there is an object. When comparing objects with `==` usually they are not equivalent, think about the common mistake with `String`-s.
The reason why it works for small numbers is that they are cached, there is a pre-instantiated set for small integers, described at [`valueOf(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)):

> `public static Integer valueOf(int i)`
>
> Returns an `Integer` instance representing the specified `int` value. If a new `Integer` instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor `Integer(int)`, as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values. This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

It is probably safe to assume that this method is used when Java is autoboxing `int`-s into `Integer`-s.

Solution: do not do that, use `int` arrays. Then it will suddenly work.

A simple test code you can try:

```
Integer a127=127;
Integer b127=127;
Integer a5000=5000;
Integer b5000=5000;
System.out.println(a127+"=="+b127+"? "+(a127==b127));
System.out.println(a5000+"=="+b5000+"? "+(a5000==b5000));
```

(See it in action on Ideone: https://ideone.com/vEry18)

---

Side remark: while symmetry is nice, I would really consider using `<` (or `>`) instead of that `Math.min()` magic, even if it results in writing `nums[i] =` twice:

```
if (nums1[nums1First] < nums2[nums2First])
{
  nums[i] = nums1[nums1First];
  if (nums1First == nums1.length - 1)
  {
    nums1[nums1First] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  }
  else
  {
    nums1First++;
  }
}
else
{
  nums[i] = nums2[nums2First];
  if (nums2First == nums2.length - 1)
  {
    nums2[nums2First] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  }
  else
  {
    nums2First++;
  }
}
```

Comment: (or use `equals` on the objects instead of `==`)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I need to use Integer instead of int for the rest of the code, but changing == to equals did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

== on Integer object was causing the issue. Find the modified version of the code.

```
public class MergeSortExample {
    public Integer[] mergeArrays(Integer[] nums1, Integer[] nums2) {
        Integer[] nums = new Integer[nums1.length + nums2.length];

        int nums1First = 0, nums2First = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums1First >= nums1.length) {
                nums[i] = nums2[nums2First];
                nums2First++;
            } else if (nums2First >= nums2.length) {
                nums[i] = nums1[nums1First];
                nums1First++;
            } else {
                nums[i] = Math.min(nums1[nums1First], nums2[nums2First]);

                if (nums[i].equals (nums1[nums1First])) {
                    nums1First++;
                } else {
                    nums2First++;
                }
            }

        }
        return nums;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] num1 = { 9, 13, 89, 5000 };
        Integer[] num2 = { 1, 89, 5001 };
        /* does not work */

        // Integer[] num1 = {9, 13, 89, 199}; //works
        // Integer[] num2 = {1, 89, 127}; //works

        MergeSortExample m = new MergeSortExample();
        Integer[] testMerge = m.mergeArrays(num1, num2);

        for (int i = 0; i < testMerge.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(testMerge[i] + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, my code is finally working! I can't believe how I used == instead of equals, it was so stupid lol!